# How can I issue a coldfusion stored procedure call and not wait for the result

Tags: stored-procedures, coldfusion

fellow ColdFusion developers. I am working in a restricted environment. I cannot make any adjustments to the timeouts, or set up an asynchronous gateway. Nor do I have access to the CF server settings. What I want to do seems simple. I want to kick off a stored procedure with arguments, and not wait for the results. In fact, the procedure updates data on its own and does not return anything. I have seen similar questions but there doesn’t seem to be a simple answer.
Any help wound be appreciated.

Comment: You could put the call to the stored procedure into a `cfthread`

Comment: @ScottStroz, you put your text in the wrong place.  It's the answer.

Answer (score 13):

Put your call to the stored procedure in a `cfthread`

Comment: iIs that the only solution, we are prohibited from using cfthread. any other work arounds you can think of?

Comment: It is pretty much the only option.

Comment: Out of curiosity... why are you prohibited from using cfthread?

Comment: We are in a shared hosted environment, there may be 100 websites on one server, they're afraid we might bring the system down

Comment: Get off the shared server.  You think the other 100 sites care if they take you down?  You can get a vps for pretty cheap now a days.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use cfthread, you could try to use cfhttp with a timeout. Move the stored procedure call out to a new page. Use cfhttp to call the new page from the place where you had the stored procedure call.

Comment: Yep, that was the old trick for simulating asynch calls back before cfthread was introduced. Not ideal, but is probably the best you can do without access to threads.